# Sending and receiving emails using node.js server

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I have to implement email server like webmail in nodeJS and angular 6.

About my scenario, 
user needs to provide their email and email password.Then I have to identify their smtp server address and authenticate.
After that user should able to send & receive email which connected to provided email.

I have researched what are the options I have and most of articles says [**node-mailer**](https://nodemailer.com/about/) is the best for sending emails but there is no feature for receive email and **node-imap** ,apart from those my best option so far is [**mailin**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailin) library.

I have try to do it in [**mailin**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailin) but I'm recently started node development with my new job and can't understand most of implementation in [**mailin**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailin) library.

If someone can help me with [**mailin**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailin) code samples or tell me if there is other options.it'll be very helpful..

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the examples from the doc:

Create folder for your project and navigate to it.

Install Mailin: `sudo npm install mailin`

Create `index.js` file with this content [source from docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailin#embedded-inside-a-node-application). `mailin.on('authorizeUser'` is not needed, you can leave it.

Start the app: `node index.js`

You need to allow the port that is used `25`. In the console in your server type `ufw allow 25`.

You need to add `DNS` record to point to your server in your hosting panel.

Now you can test the server with `Telnet` in your PC. Try to connect to it with:

`telnet domain-for-the-server.com 25`

You can send an email to `doesntmatterthename@domain-for-the-server.com`

The event that you need `index.js` is `mailin.on('message'...`. You can type `console.log(data);`, restart the app and when you send mail, you will see the data in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still trying to receive emails with Node JS i would recommend [node-mailin](https://github.com/vithalreddy/node-mailin). It is almost the same as mailin (which is not mainted anymore). Emails sent to your server get parsed as JSON and you can do anything with them. You can also reject emails based on the senders email address or IP or if it is send to an email adress you don't want to be used.